# Recursive delete DS_Store files from folders and subfolders in AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way to batch delete DS_Store files that are spread out across many, many different folders and subfolders within an individual S3 bucket in the CLI?

I can find documentation about deleting these files if they're in a bucket or one folder, but not how to find and delete every DS_Store file across many folders within a given bucket.

Answer (score 9):

That's possible with the aws cli.

NB: I've appended the *--dryrun* option, so you can verify the files before you are going to delete them.

```
aws s3 rm s3://bucket.example.com --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.DS_Store" --dryrun
```